# Unable to Pick Up Nearby Beacons When Building Ionic Cordova App

Tags: cordova, ionic3, ibeacon

I am trying to create a sample ionic cordova iOS app that scans for nearby beacons and prints them (with associated data) to the UI. Values should change with proximity.

I have been following the below example (but using publish/subscribe for events):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ibeacon/

My problem is that, after subscribing to didStartMonitoringForRegion events, the resulting BeaconList returns 'undefined is not an object'. I can't seem to pick up any nearby beacons. I have confirmed that they do exist using '[Core Beacons](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/core-beacons/id1350862272?mt=8)'. Twenty of them.

I am setting the UUID of my phone below - I am getting it from this.device.uuid:

> BeaconRegion('deskBeacon', 'A2E19874-3A63-4574-84B8-4720D0934099');

Should I be explicitly naming the nearby beacon UUIDs I am scanning for (doesn't seem right)?

Not sure why I am not picking up nearby beacons. Advice appreciated.

XCode 10.1
Ionic v3
Cordova 6.1.0

**HOME.TS**

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { NavController, Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

    // plugins

    import { BeaconProvider } from '../../providers/beacon-provider'
    import { BeaconModel } from '../../models/beacon-model';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {

      beacons: BeaconModel[] = [];
      zone: any;


      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public platform: Platform,
        public beaconProvider: BeaconProvider, public events: Events) 
        {
            // required for UI update
          this.zone = new NgZone({ enableLongStackTrace: false });

        }

        ionViewDidLoad() {
          this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.beaconProvider.initialise()
            .then((isInitialised) => {
              if (isInitialised) {
                this.startScanningForBeaconEvents();
              }
            }).catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
              console.log(err.errors);
            });
          });
        }

        startScanningForBeaconEvents() {
          this.events.subscribe('didStartMonitoringForRegion', (data) => {
            // update the UI with the beacon list  
            this.zone.run(() => {
              this.beacons = [];
              let beaconList = data.beacons;

              beaconList.forEach((beacon) => {
                let beaconObject = new BeaconModel(beacon);
                this.beacons.push(beaconObject);
                console.log("nearby beacon " + beaconObject.uuid + " has been added");
              });
            });
        });

      }
    }
```

**BEACONPROVIDER.TS**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IBeacon } from '@ionic-native/ibeacon'
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device'; 

@Injectable()
export class BeaconProvider {

  delegate: any;
  beaconRegion: any;
  uuid: any;
  isAdvertisingAvailable: boolean = null;

  constructor(private platform: Platform, private device: Device, 
    private ibeacon: IBeacon, public events: Events) {
      this.ibeacon = ibeacon;
      this.device = device;
      this.events = events;
      this.platform = platform;
      this.enableDebugLogs();
  }

  public enableDebugLogs(): void {
    this.platform.ready().then(async () => {
      this.ibeacon.enableDebugLogs();
      this.ibeacon.enableDebugNotifications();
    });
  }

  initialise(): any {

    this.uuid = this.device.uuid;

    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // we need to be running on a device 
      if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        // Request permission to use location on iOS
        this.ibeacon.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
        // create a new delegate and register it with the native layer
        this.delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();
        // Subscribe to some of the delegate's event handlers
        this.delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion()
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.events.publish('didRangeBeaconsInRegion', data);
            },
              error => console.error()
            );
        this.delegate.didStartMonitoringForRegion()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.events.publish('deskBeacon', data);
          },
          error => console.error()
          );
        this.delegate.didEnterRegion()
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.events.publish('didEnterRegion', data);
          },
          error => console.error()
          );
        this.delegate.didExitRegion().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.events.publish('didExitRegion', data);
          },
          error => console.error()
          );
        // setup a beacon region
        this.beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion('deskBeacon', 'A2E19874-3A63-4574-84B8-4720D0934099');

        this.ibeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(this.beaconRegion)
          .then(() => {
            resolve(true);
          }).catch(error => {
            resolve(false);
          });
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });

    return promise;
  }

}
```

**APP.MODULE.TS**

```
import { BeaconProvider } from '../providers/beacon-provider'
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IBeacon } from '@ionic-native/ibeacon'
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { Device } from '@ionic-native/device';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    IBeacon,
    BeaconProvider,
    Device,
    { provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert using this ionic3 cordova plugin, but I suspect that this is not  the correct callback for your ranging results:

```
this.events.subscribe('didStartMonitoringForRegion', (data) => {
```

That appears to be a callback indicating that ranging started successfully, and if true, then it would not be a surprise that `data.beacons` is undefined.  You probably want to get the list of beacons from the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` callback.

Comment: Thanks, David. I tried that callback initially. I think you are right, that is likely the callback I should be using. However, the result is the same, I am not able to pickup nearby beacons. the beacon array is always empty.

Comment: OK, is it empty or undefined?  A zero length array is a very different thing, and may indicate one of several other things is not satisfied for it to work:  (1) bluetooth is off on the phone (2) location is off on the phone (3) the location permission has not been granted t your app -- check in Settings -> Apps -> your app

Comment: I have checked all those possibilities, the phone seems set up correctly. The response is "undefined". Maybe some code issue I am not seeing on my side. I am looking into that right now.

Comment: I would print out your data object to the console `console.log("Ranging result: "+JSON.stringify(data))` to make sure the object you are getting back is what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, David. That produces:  {"region":{"typeName":"BeaconRegion","uuid":"A2E19874-3A63-4574-84B8-4720D0934099","identifier":"deskBeacon"},"eventType":"didRangeBeaconsInRegion","beacons":[]} All looks good except the lonely looking beacon array. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Ok, great, at least it is not undefined.  And you are absolutely sure that the same phone sees those beacons with that *exact* uuid with another app?  And you have confirmed in settings that your new app has been granted location when in use permission?

Comment: Hi David - sorry for the looong delay. Work got busy and my pet project got a back seat. Now back at it. I am still stuck on this. Could I get a bit more clarity on this: "are you absolutely sure that the same phone sees those beacons with that exact uuid with another app?" As I understand it, PhoneA & PhoneB should be looking for beacons (eachother) in the following region:BeaconRegion('deskBeacon', 'A2E19874-3A63-4574-84B8-4720D0934099'); When I load my code on the phone, it is the exact same code for each, I make no changes per phone. Can you could advise on how I should be testing?

Comment: Are you transmitting a hardware beacon nearby with that UUID?  If so, can you see it with the Beacon Locate app in the App Store (you will have to configure it to look for this UUID).

Comment: As a follow-up to this, I have a question. I am trying to get two phones to recognize each-other. Not a phone and a beacon device. To do that, I am wondering if I need to tell the phones to "advertise" themselves. I don't have code in place that explicitly does that, but it makes sense that I should. Can you advise? Thanks again.

Comment: OK, looks like I just answered my own question. The problem was I wasn't advertising. Phones can now see eachother. Thanks for the help, David.